# Google map not displaying object labels (street names and etc)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am creating an app which is based on `google map sdk`, some time ago I noticed that my apps map is less detailed than other apps maps.
So I created new project with google map activity generate `API key` and it is more detailed. I am not using any custom style.
Would you please help me to make my app more detailed?

see pictures below to see the differences :

my app:
[image]

Other sample of map app:
[image]

Comment: Could you add code, so that we can see how you implement maps in your app?

Comment: here is an init of map https://pastebin.com/TLV2ck01

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue caused by the fact that I set the map's locale to `ka_GE` and seems like details was missing because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Check what kind of type of map you have implemented in your app. Seek this line in your code:

```
yourMapName.setMapType();
```

And set it to hybrid like this:

```
yourMapName.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

Comment: Just a normal map works well to newly created project.